# images are displayed incorrectly after chrome 77 update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, dropzone.js

In our web site we could upload several image together using dropzone.
After chrome update for android the big size images after compression appears as black images.
But we don't have this problem in ios or desktop chrome and the problem is only in android chrome.
I suspect it is caused by native lazy loading. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers as well on Android or just in Chrome?

Comment: In Microsoft Edge works properly, in opera mini has the same problem as chrome. And Firefox seems that not compatible with dropzone.

Comment: I found out that the problem is in image compression with 'canvas'

Comment: You could write an answer to have this as a solved question and serve as a reference to other people with this problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reproduced GPU memory leak with drawing canvas into another canvas:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1011812
May be it is the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrey. It was a memory leak and the problem is there. I took a handle from previous canvas and put it as null.

Answer (score 2):

Finally after checking all the compression algorithm I found out the problem in Android Chrome 77.

In our algorithm, after loading image from file, we use canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage to draw image into the canvas. Then for resizing the picture we use the  drawImage() on canvas to have new canvas and hear is the chrome broke the algorithm.
The brief answer is canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage function works with image as input correctly bu not with a canvas as input.

To solve the problem we first calculate the correct width and height and the read the image with the desired dimensions.

works:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width/2;
    canvas.height = img.height/2;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

and doesn't work:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.width = canvas.width / 2;
    newCanvas.height = canvas.height / 2;
    newCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
```

In the end of the day, Chrome 77 can not draw canvas from canvas.