# Does Google Chrome v77 have a HTML5-Canvas bug?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

We run the graphical part of our software in Canvas. With the latest version of Google Chrome (v77) being released, our product doesn't display anything on load. Canvas simply doesn't draw anything.

When you resize the windows or scroll, Canvas draws the elements correctly, but not initially. For every refresh, we are back to a blank page. 
If we disable Accelerated 2D canvas, it works. We have tried the upcoming versions of Google Chrome (v78 and v79), and here canvas renders and draws correctly.

Does anybody experience anything similar, i.e. is it a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropzonejs doesn't work with Chrome 77 on Android. It is probably same isue with canvas.

[more on this isue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58094755/images-are-displayed-incorrectly-after-chrome-77-update)